# RLE Compression and Decompression Implementation in C90

Tags: c, encoding, compression

I'm kind of stuck on implementing the various conditions in the `if` statement to print out the correct output for RLE compression.

It is half working but outputting the wrong structure.

This is the characters in the input file "`AAAAAA333333FFFFF22222`" but then this is the compressed output: "`2536A6F5`", the output should be "`6A635F52`".

May anybody give me hints what I need to add in my `if` statement so it prints it out correctly?

Also may anybody give me hints on implementing RLE decompression (decoding)?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{
    int count[256] = { 0 };
    int n;
    int p;
    FILE * fp;
    FILE * fptr;
    fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    fptr = fopen("compressed_test.txt", "w");

    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error file doesn't exist\n");
        printf("Nothing to compress\n");
        exit(0);

    }   

    while((n=fgetc(fp)))
    {
        if(n == EOF)
        {
            break;
        }   
        else
        count[n]+=1;
    }

    for (p=0; p < 256; p++)
    {
        if (count[p] > 0)
        {
            fprintf(fptr, "%c%d", p, count[p]);
            printf("Compression completed successfully\n");
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at `fprintf(fptr, "%c%d", p, count[p]);` Which one is the letter, and which one is the count? You're also not preserving the order that the letters are in the file.

Comment: p is the letter, count[p] is the number, it's printing it out in the wrong order, which leads me to think I need to implement more conditions in the if statement.

Comment: That's my point, your `fprintf` is wrong. If you want `6A` then it's count then letter. That won't fix the problem that you're not doing it in the order the letters come from the file. You need to compress as you go, especially if there can be more than one run of a letter.

Comment: If the input was AAABBBAAABBBAAA is it supposed to print 9A6B or 3A3B3A3B3A?

Comment: @immibis It's supposed to print out 9A6B, I think my compression logic is missing something cause from reading Retired Ninja's statement I need to compress as I go but it's doing all at once which won't work.

Comment: `"%c%d" means, take the first argument, p, and print it as a character, then take the next argument, count[p], and print it as an integer. They are both backward from what you described you want.

Comment: What Retired Ninja said... you say that you want it to print the count first, then the character, but your code is telling the computer to print the character first, then the number.

Comment: Also is BBBAAABBBAAABBB supposed to print 6A9B or 9B6A?

Comment: Also the way you have it designed now, decompression is not possible.

Comment: It's supposed to print out 9B6A

Comment: So do I have to rewrite the whole compression logic again?

Comment: Maybe, I want to sure you understand this point though - if you have the compressed file 9B6A, and you want to decompress it, how can you tell whether the uncompressed file was BAAAAAABBBBBBBB or BBBAAABBBAAABBB or BBBBBBBBBAAAAAA? (you don't need a computer to answer this question)

Comment: Yeah I need to implement when it compresses each character at a time and when it has to decompressed make it decompress one character at a time?

Comment: Here is an example of compressing as you read. This will give you a result you can decompress to get back what you started with, assuming your count is never greater than 9. If your count can be greater than 9 you would need to do something different. https://ideone.com/47Q6aS

Comment: Not only do you have to rewrite the whole compression logic. You need to rethink the entire compression design. Imagine that the compressed file is `11112`. Is that one 1 followed by eleven 2's. Or is it eleven 1's followed by one 2.

Comment: Yeah in my case it would be greater than 9, so do I need to write a condition if it's greater than 9 do this?

Comment: I don't think you understand what the code is supposed to do. Maybe it will help make sure you can do it yourself (it's not hard), before you try to make the computer do it.